# python scikits learn - SVM options

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikits, scikit-learn

Just curious about two options in scikits learn SVM class. What does Scale_C and shrinking do? There wasn't much in the documentation. Scale C seems to be able to scale the C paramter appropriately for the training data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`scale_C=True` (deprecated in the dev version and scheduled for removal in 0.12) causes the regularization parameter `C` to be divided by the number of samples before it is handed to the underlying LibSVM implementation.

`shrinking` enables or disables the "shrinking heuristic", described by [Joachims 1999](http://www.joachims.org/publications/joachims_99a.ps.gz), that should speed up SVM training.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. How does dividing C by the number of samples help with the SVM training?

Comment: @tomas: setting it to `True` makes the regularization independent of the number of samples. When set to `False`, you have to double it when the number of samples doubles, etc. I suggest you always set it to `True`; I believe that's going to be the future behavior.

Comment: In any case the value of C should be selected by cross-validate grid search on the development set. Neither is intrinsically better that the other. You just need to know that C is no longer scaled by the number of sample in the dev version of scikit-learn in case you are interested its absolute value and how it is used in the objective function (e.g. for publishing a scientific journal).